# how to get a control on a particular form after clicking submit button when i have multiple forms in a single page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

after reloading the page, the control should be on a particular form.
i tried but its not working please help me guys..

```css
form{width:100px; height:200px;}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <form name="1"><input type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE">      </form>
   <form name="2"><input type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE">      </form>
   <form name="3"><input type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE">      </form>
   <form name="4"><input type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE">      </form>
   <form name="5"><input type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE">      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

like this i am having forms, if i click on submit button of form 3, then it should save the content and reload and it should take me back to the form 3.

Comment: Try to set hash value in url while reloading page and use same value into name attribute on form element.

Comment: To be honest I didn't get it. What exactly do you want? Maybe you're looking for ajax calls?

Comment: @Alex if its possible with Ajax call also its ok .. tell me how can i?..

Comment: @kag i don't know how to set hash value.. please can you explain..

Comment: location.hash= "#form1"

Comment: @Nagaraj just create js code snippet which handle submit button to send request and send back response

Comment: just use $('#one').modal('show');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
 <form name="1" id="one">
   <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="one" />
  <input type="button" name="one" value="SAVE1">      
 </form>
```

```js
 header('Location:page_name.php#'.$_POST['form_id']);
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Add `id="one"` in each form  and set the `form id` into `value of  hidden input` field like this .

```
 <form name="1" id="one">
   <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="one" />
  <input type="button" name="one" value="SAVE1">      
 </form>
```

**PHP :**

```
//do your all stuff here 
// finally add last submitted form id like this  

 header('Location:page_name.php#'.$_POST['form_id']);
```

Comment: that you did't not mention it in your question . @Nagaraj

Comment: if you want show last submited form . just use $('#one').modal('show');

Comment: add unique id for each form id="one"    id="two" like this and each form insert one hidden input like this <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="one" />   with value equal to same as form id . so after form submit ion you can the which form submitted easily . so you can redirect again with # id

Comment: header('Location:page_name.php#'.$_POST['form_id']);       how to use this in jquery?.. @JYoThI

Comment: use like this in php side header('Location:page_name.php?modal='.$_POST['form_id']);  and in page use $('#'+$_GET['modal']).modal('show');

Comment: $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "php/Immunization/save_immunization",
     
     success: function(data){
      alert("Data Saved Successfully"); 
       
       window.location.href =("child_immunization.php");
      }
     });

Comment: are using ajax for form posting ? or ordinary form submition ?

Comment: i am using ajax in jquery so after coming to success i need to refresh the page after which i need to go for a particular form.